# IIS FTP user authentication won't work

Tags: authentication, iis, ftp

I have:

- Added the ftp-publishing service
- Allowed IIS-Authentication in the management service
- Created a user under IIS Manager-User
- Allowed the user in IIS-Manager-Permissions
- Added the user to FTP-Authentication rules for my site
- Added the IISAuthentication to the FTP Authentication rules
- IIS_IUSERS has full access to the directory

Yet, I get the login prompt but it won't take my login credentials.

Any ideas ?

Comment: what about the underlying directories of the ftp site?

Comment: The ftp points to the root directory of the site.

Comment: yes, and whatever user you're connecting as will need to have ntfs rights to access that directory.

Comment: Uh I did not know that. It's an IIS user though, how do I give it ntfs permissions ? IIS_IUSERS has full access

Comment: After 8years here is my experience, I set everything up but my user have same random password like: Jndsuz1d2@3### and it didn't work, after I change password to Jndsuz1d23jdHS (only words+numbers) everything woks fine, In my case  was error 530